# Validate API of a web site

Tags: javascript, php, validation, web-api-testing

I am new on this stuff and this could be a simple question, but I want to validate the APIs came from a web site.

I am a reseller for a company with my own web site. All users are registered on the main company's website through my website which means usernames/passwords are stored with company's web site.
Now, I have some stuff on my web site which I want to show only to the registered users. Also, I have the API's to check username and password combination of any user which in return I get similar to the following message with the help of (`file_get_contents`):

If successful:

```
***<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
  <!DOCTYPE ValidateUser (View Source for full doctype...)> 
- <ValidateUser>
  <Customer>james</Customer> 
  <Result>Success</Result> 
  </ValidateUser>***
```

OR if failed, then:

```
***<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
  <!DOCTYPE ValidateUser (View Source for full doctype...)> 
- <ValidateUser>
  <Customer>james</Customer> 
  <Result>Failed</Result> 
  <Reason>User/Password combination unknown</Reason> 
  </ValidateUser>***
```

That was the situation, and I was thinking to write a PHP code with if statement which can check or validate the above message came from the API request, on basis of that I can allow or reject a user to visit that particular page on my web site.

Hope it makes sense to you.

Comment: javascript validation is purely for page performance and provides no actual security.

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: SO what is the question? Everything you've written seems legit so far

Comment: Sorry to make it confusing, but my question is how to code that php script which can validate the results from api request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [PHP SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php). Parsing should be fairly easy using that.

Some code similar to the following should do the trick:

```
$result = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/validate?username=john&pwd=mypwdhash');
$simpleXML = new SimpleXMLElement($result);

if ($simpleXML->ValidateUser[0]->Result == "Success"){
   // success
} else{
  // fail
}
```

Alternatively, you can just search for the word "success" within the XML string.

On a side-note: Using this methodology to authenticate users is not so safe, as it involves GET requests in which you mention usernames and password hashes (I assume you do use a password hash and not the plaintext password, right?).

Comment: Hi,
I tried the above method and I didn't completely understand the meaning if if statement.
I copied the code above, changed the url and tried to echo '$simpleXML' but nothing displayed.
please explain it for me.
thanks

Comment: The simpleXML API parses the XML and organizes it for you in an object/array. In other words, it is normal that echo does not output anything (as echo only works for literals). Try print_r($simpleXML).  The if statement should check whether the Result tag contains the text 'Success'. Also, I recommend to read the documentation I linked to understand better how the simpleXML api works.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to hear this - but this method of shared passwords is really not a great setup provided by the third party site in question. It essentially means users are inputting passwords to you (a third party if I got it right) for the other site. If there is authenticated access for you to user data on your side they should probably be using openAuth for this (http://www.oauth.net) rather than sharing passwords...

I'm not necessarily saying you should advise them of it (since it'll probably cost you work) but I'd think about it. If there's a security breach on their side fingers might point back to you because you had access to some of the passwords.